# C# safely build an SQL string to execute using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm executing some SQL using EF with the `.SqlQuery(string sql)` command.

I want to make sure my sql string is completely sanitised, so the logic approach was to use an `SqlCommand` object with parameters to build it.

However I don't want to execute it using the SqlCommand, I just want the SqlCommand to spit out a string that I can plug into my EF `.SqlQuery(...)` call.

Is there a way of doing this, or another method of ensuring my `.SqlQuery` won't result in injection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doesn't EF support that out of the box?

You should be able to call `SqlQuery` with parameters, so it will take care of SQL injection etc., just like `SqlCommand` does:

```
var tests = context.Database.SqlQuery<Test>(
    @"SELECT Id, Name FROM tests where Name={0}", "TestName");
```

or..

```
var tests = context.Database.SqlQuery<Test>(
    @"SELECT Id, Name FROM tests where Name=@name", 
    new SqlParameter("@name", "TestName"));
```

Comment: Facepalm. So it does!

Comment: I can't get this to work. I've tried both methods above and I just get the error "Must declare the table variable "@name". Infuriating there is no documentation on it

Comment: Are you trying to pass the table name as a parameter as well? That is not going to work. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003241/must-declare-the-table-variable-table) Do you really need the table name to be variable?

Comment: I like the first syntax as it is very clean and works a lot like string.Format so it's easy to understand.  Plus, under the hood it uses parameters so sql injection is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Get the CommandText property of the SqlCommand.

```
string query = cmd.CommandText;

foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
{
    query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but the command text only gives me back my original string - it doesn't put the parameters into it: eg `SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE @propertyName = @searchQuery`

Comment: Re: Edit - is that not the same as simply using a stringbuilder? - Just tried it and it is. It doesn't sanitise or anything.

Comment: I believe(but might be wrong) that the SqlCommand object will protect you.