# Is it unsecure to refer tablename in methodparameter,because of sql injection?

Tags: c#, sql

I'am working on a SQL engine and to prevent sql injection i have used sql parameters.

But on the other hand I refer the tablename from the methodparameter

it look's like this for a simple example:

```
public void dosomething(string tablename)
{
string query = "select productname, price from " + tablename;

...

}
```

Now my question: is this unsecure?

Comment: A table name cannot pass with sql parameters. Your sample is insecure if multiple statement is able to run, imagine `tablename = "item; Drop table item"`

Comment: It's safe if you have control of the table name. It would be very dangerous if you expect the user to supply the name without some very thorough sanitisation

Comment: could you give a sample how to secure this function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17947836/1287352

Answer (score 0):

You could check this yourself, what would happen if you ran this like so:

```
dosomething("Product;DROP TABLE Product;--")
```

Which assumes a table of product.  Particularly going to be a problem if your tablename parameter is coming from user input.

Comment: ok, thank you for the quick answer, do you have a solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely unsecure if user is supplying the tablename.
 As best practice  ,instead of constructing the statements , they can be mapped or selected based on user inputs via ifs-case etc over predefined strings in your code. This will eliminate basic sql injection attacks like Eric said .

Also ,one more  layer can be introduced via OOPS tricks  so that DDL,DML and DCL are clearly separated in your query engine so that even the rare sql injection attacks are eliminated.

Comment: It's not 'definitely insecure'. It's only a problem if the OP is allowing a user to supply the tablename directly. If the tablename is being supplied by the software without user input there's no problem here at all.