# Use sql table like sql parameter in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlparameter

I have query with sql parameters. My parameter must be my table from database and I don't now how I can realize this.

I did it so:

```
myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand()
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
myCommand.CommandText =
"SELECT Id, Bez, Param5, Info from Table" & "@idFixed"
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@idFixed", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strIdFixed
```

`strIdFixed`(transmitted parameter) must be something id, because I have many tables with names `Table01,` `Table02,` `Table333` ....

Comment: You usually cannot specify the table name as a parameter in a prepared statement, because allowing this would be a security risk and would defeat the point of the statement.  If you need to query a certain table in a safe way, then create a prepared statement for that specific table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it

```
Dim tableName As String = "Test" + strIdFixed.ToString.Trim
Dim builder = New SqlCommandBuilder()
Dim escapedTableName As String = builder.QuoteIdentifier(tableName)

myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand()
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
myCommand.CommandText =
"SELECT Id, Bez, Param5, Info from " + escapedTableName
```

Thank https://stackoverflow.com/a/17948039/6787667